# Installing Leiningen 2.6.0 (zip file)

Tags: windows, clojure, leiningen

I recently attempted to upgrade my leiningen install on a Windows XP (sp3) machine using both lein upgrade and lein self-install. Unfortunately, both attempts were unsuccessful as one can clearly see below:

```
C:\>lein upgrade
The script at C:\lein.bat will be upgraded to the latest stable version.
Do you want to continue (Y/N)?Y
Downloading latest Leiningen batch script...
--2016-02-06 10:36:08--  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/raw/stable/bin/lein.bat
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.131
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.131|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Serve
r CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Failed to download https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/raw/stable/bin/lein.bat



C:\>lein self-install
Downloading Leiningen now...
--2016-02-06 10:39:39--  https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.6.0/leiningen-
2.6.0-standalone.zip
Resolving github.com (github.com)... 192.30.252.131
Connecting to github.com (github.com)|192.30.252.131|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify github.com's certificate, issued by 'CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Serve
r CA,OU=www.digicert.com,O=DigiCert Inc,C=US':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to github.com insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.

Failed to download https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/releases/download/2.6.0/leiningen-2.6.0-
standalone.zip

It is possible that the download failed due to "powershell",
"curl" or "wget"'s inability to retreive GitHub's security certificate.
The suggestions below do not check certificates, so use this only if
you understand the security implications of not doing so.

Curl failed to download the latest Leiningen version.
Try to use "wget" to download Leiningen by setting up
the HTTP_CLIENT environment variable with one of the following
values:

 "  a) set HTTP_CLIENT=curl -f -L -k -o"

NOTE: make sure *not* to add double quotes to set the value of
      HTTP_CLIENT

If neither curl nor wget can download Leiningen, please seek
for help on Leiningen's GitHub project issues page.
```

Using the --no-check-certificate option also failed to resolve the issue.

In a attempt to satiate my intellectual curiosity, I manually downloaded leiningen-2.6.0-standalone.zip, but I am unsure of how to proceed with the install so I can use leiningen in the customary manner. Would I sinmply upzip the file to a folder, e.g., C:\lein, and add it to my path? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`lein upgrade` works for me on Linux.

http://leiningen.org/ links to a Windows installer - http://leiningen-win-installer.djpowell.net/ maybe that would work?

Answer (score 0):

Reading that message it seems that `curl` failed and you should try again, but this time making sure that `wget` will be used instead of `curl`. You should do that by having a system environment variable called `HTTP_CLIENT` set as they say. I admit that it is a bit odd that you are setting it to `curl`, which you are supposedly trying to disable. So my interpretation here may be wrong, but I would just go with the instructions regardless.

Best to use Control Panel to set the system environment variable, that way the issue with those spaces should be taken care of for you. Then use `set` from the command line to make sure it is there before running `lein self-install` again.

> simply upzip the file to a folder, e.g., C:\lein, and add it to my path?

Sounds like an even better idea!